# javamail smtp authentication with certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to authenticate with an SMTP relay via TLS with javamail using only a certificate and not using any login credentials?  Or is the certificate necessary for negotiating a secure transfer of the login credentials?  I'm confused as to how this piece works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, TLS is used in SMTP to secure transfer and protect login credentials and I didn't see real-world cases when the client-side certificate alone is used for authentication (in SMTP). But I can imagine such *custom* system where the server will authenticate the client based on his certificate. Of course, this depends on server's and client's capability to use the certificate for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping I could do something similar to key based authentication used with ssh.

Comment: @mav you can, if you write both the client and the server.

Comment: So it will not be possible if I use smtp relay with an existing Exchange server or sendmail?

Comment: I am not an exchange expert but I think no, this would not be possible.